# Show all content from one table and only matching from the other

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables, "CategoriesTable" and "CompanyTable" I need to show all the entries from the categories table and only the entry (in the category_b in the company table.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM categories INNER JOIN company ON categories.category = company.category_b WHERE id_com=". $id );

CategoriesTable        CompanyTable

category                category_b
----------------        ----------------
Vendor                  Client
Employee
Client
Prospect
```

This is within a drop down menu where the current category stored in the CompanyTable.category_b should show first. If the user wants to change the category the drop down will display the available categories in the category table.

This query only shows the matching entries between each table, so it only displays "Client".

Comment: you want a left join, not an inner join.

Comment: I guess I don't want to match the data I just want to show the data from both fields in two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN company ON categories.category = company.category_b WHERE id_com=". $id
```

Comment: Just shows the category in company table. This is a drop down and I am wanting the company category to show first then if they want to change they can drop down and view all the category choices from categories table.

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe what you are trying to do a little more? Maybe post the table schema and some data?

Comment: Do you have id fields in either table?

Comment: Yes. CategoriesTable = id_cat and CompanyTable = id_com